# How to replace fragment of parent layout from child

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

I have looked at many of the similar question But still I'm unable to replace container layout (FrameLayout) of My Main Activity from a fragment that is visible in that container.
Here is what I'm trying to do I have a main activity with navigation drawer and On navigation drawer item click I'm changing fragment accordingly, I'm successful till this. These fragments are Login, Register, Categories, Contact Us etc. I'm changing/replacing fragments with `FragmentManager`, `FragmentTransaction` its  method replace. Check the code below

```
public void changeFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragMain();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FragPrivacyPolicy();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            case 101:
                fragment = new FragLogin();
                break;
            case 102:
                fragment = new FragRegister();
                break;
            case 103:
                fragment = new FragEditAccount();
                break;
            case 104:
                fragment = new FragOrderHistory();
                break;
            case 105:
                fragment = new FragForgotPass();
                break;
            case 106:
                fragment = new FragOrderDetail();
                break;
            case 108:
                fragment = new FragAboutUs();
                break;
            case 109:
                fragment = new FragContactUs();
                break;
            case 110:
                fragment = new FragMain();
                break;
        }

        transaction.replace(R.id.flFragments, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Which is working fine as all my fragments `extends Fragment`. The problem comes when I try to call this method in one of the fragments visible in this `mainActivity`'s container. Suppose I have a textView in `FragLogin` saying "Don't have an account Register" so on click this textView I have to open `FragRegister` in the same container of mainActivity. When I do it like this in my `FragLogin` App Crashes pointing to the `transaction.commit();`

```
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
activity.changeFragment(102);
```

And when I try like this

```
    FragRegister fragRegister = new  FragRegister();
//    Fragment fragRegister = new  FragRegister();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.Id.flFragments, fragRegister).commit();
```

It does not recognize the `R.Id.flFragments` as its inside the mainActivity not in FragLogin.

So how can I replace that FragRegister in `mainActivity`'s container from FragLogin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `getChildFragmentManager()` because it belongs to the fragment manager and the container that is holding current fragment is the activity container.Instead use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Also see this stament

```
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
activity.changeFragment(102);
```

You are creating a new object of `mainactivity` which is already created.You have to call the activity method from fragments using `getActivity()`.Call the changeFragment method like this.

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeFragment(102);
```

Comment: thank you its working now :) with `getActivity()` now both methods are working well.

Comment: Your most Welcome.If my answer helped please accept it :)

Comment: I upvoted because there is time limit to accept answer. Now accepted as well.